# Android Animation Custom Interpolar Issue [overshotInterpolar]

Tags: android, android-animation

In my app , i want to use *overshootInterpolator[android.R.anim.overshoot_interpolator].*

Now ive created my custom overshootInterpolar in which ive set my own overshoot value.
But by default in overshootInterpolar the effect is like follows
Its accelerates right on start and slows down and then overshoots and come back.

What i want is it should not accelerate right on start.

So this is what i have tried
without success

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<overshootInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@anim/hdr_accelerate_interpolar"
    android:tension="1.3" />
```

**Attribute:** android:tension

**Description:** The amount of tension, the default is 2.
A larger tension will make the overshoot smaller and quicker.

**@anim/hdr_accelerate_interpolar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accelerateInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:factor="2" />
```

**Attribute:** android:factor

**Description:** A larger value causes a slower initial motion and a
faster acceleration towards the end.

**MY ISSUE: The accelerate interpolar is not taking effect.**

Comment: do what should it do at start?

Comment: You have stated what is your expected behaviour, but what is the observed behaviour? What really happens when you use your code? Is there an animation at all and if yes, what does it do?

Comment: there is no effect of the accelerate_interpolar that i have added,i.e the overshootInterpolar remains unchanged even if i add this  android:interpolator="@anim/hdr_accelerate_interpolar"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to combine two interpolators into one by specifying an `android:interpolator` attribute within an interpolator resource. Unfortunately, this is not possible using XML resources and you will have to write your custom interpolator as a Java class and also set the interpolator on you animation programmatically.

As an example, your interpolator could look like this.

```
public class AccelerateOvershootInterpolator implements Interpolator
{
  private AccelerateInterpolator accelerate;
  private OvershootInterpolator overshoot;

  public AccelerateOvershootInterpolator(float factor, float tension)
  {
    accelerate = new AccelerateInterpolator(factor);
    overshoot = new OvershootInterpolator(tension);
  }

  @Override
  public float getInterpolation(float input)
  {
    return overshoot.getInterpolation(accelerate.getInterpolation(input));
  }

}
```

Of course you don't need to use the `AccelerateInterpolator` or the `OvershootInterpolator`. The `getInterpolation` method can apply any mathematical function to the input. To use this interpolator for an animation you need to create an instance of the interpolator and set it on your animation, like this.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.my_animation);
AccelerateOvershootInterpolator interpolator = new AccelerateOvershootInterpolator(2.0f,  1.7f);
animation.setInterpolator(interpolator);
animatedView.startAnimation(animation);
```

For an overview on interpolators and how to implement your own, you can look at this tutorial http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1078